# Highcharts xAxis drilldown dont change correctly

Tags: jquery, highcharts, label

http://jsfiddle.net/ZBXV7/2/

```
when I click a column or label the xAxis write incorrect label but tooltip its ok.

Where's the problem?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `"categories": [...]` from your xAxis decalaration. If each point in the series has a `name` it will use that for the xAxis labels.

Comment: Thanks! You save my days.